# Solution for Portainer Docker Nginx: Unhealthy and Bad Gateway 502

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, portainer

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Raspberry Pi3 with Portainer 2.5.1, Docker/Docker-Compose, Nginx Reverse Proxy (jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest) and yobasystems/alpine-mariadb:10.4.17-arm32v7 for my Icecast2 Server to provide an https stream. After reboot Nginx was always unhealthy or I got a Bad Gateway Error.So, I played around with it and I guess, I found a little solution for the Nginx unhealty Error und the Bad Gateway Error. You don't have to uninstall or remove any installed container. In both situations you can try these steps.

The only thing I did, was: Navigate as root to /home/*user*/nginx and delete the folders "data" and "letsencrypt" . These are the configuration folders for Nginx Reverse Proxy.

If you got portainer running go to your browser in your portainer admin interface, change to Containers, and restar "nginx_app_1". Open a new tab and navigat to x.x.x.x:81 for the Nginx Proxy Manager admin interface. Reload the page until login screen comes up. Log in with admin@example.com and PW: changeme. If you had it running in the past and the first login doesn't work, use your login which you changed at first install. Then test the connection with your DDNS Service URL and check if the Default Site message of Nginx Proxy Manager comes up.

Now you are able to setup your Proxy Host and Certificte again. For the first time don't use https in the Scheme field and be shure the switches are off. Change to SSL, type your domain and activate Force SSL and HTTP/2 Support. This worked in my case.

Hope that will help you a little bit.

Kind regards, Reini

Further install tutorials:
Install Python 3.8 (Not 3.9! Doesn't work):
https://maker-tutorials.com/python3-pip-raspberry-pi-installieren/

Install Docker and Portainer:
https://www.wundertech.net/portainer-raspberry-pi-install-how-to-install-docker-and-portainer/

Install Docker-Compose: sudo apt install docker-compose:
https://linuxhint.com/install-docker-compose-on-ubuntu/

Install Nginx Reverse Proxy:
On Raspberry use "yobasystems/alpine-mariadb:10.4.17-arm32v7" in docker-compose.yml !!
https://www.wundertech.net/nginx-proxy-manager-raspberry-pi-install-instructions/